# Testing Rich Media Ads with Browser Automation

Tags: testing, selenium, ads

I'm doing Advertising Quality Assurance for a big website, basically in testing terms we are in Medieval times over here.

I'd like to add some kind of automated testing to the table and tried Selenium IDE as a start. Thing is, been playing with it and it doesn't record any of the interactions I need to test with the creatives we have, like expandables, push downs, billboards, you know all that stuff we all hate.

Is this happening because the ads are mainly built in Flash?

Is there any kind of automated testing or any kind of thing you could think in order to avoid manual testing for rich ads?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying Sikuli for this.  It works on image recognition and should do anything you want to do except possibly animations...but then most automation tools can't do those either.

http://www.sikuli.org/